# Remove line from file that contains string more than once

Tags: regex, sed, command-line, grep

I need to remove all the lines inside a file that contains a certain string more than once, for example if my file is like this:

```
This is a test toRemove first line

This is a test toRemove second line toRemove
```

Should produce a file like with only the first line

```
This is a test toRemove first line
```

I am trying to do this on linux from command line and I tried to use grep or sed like this

```
grep -d "toRemove.*toRemove" myFile > myOtherFile

sed '/\toRemove.*toRemove/!d' myFile > myOtherFile
```

But nothing seems to work. Does anybody know how to obtain this?

Comment: It should be `sed '/toRemove.*toRemove/d' myFile > myOtherFile`. `\t` matches a TAB char, and `!d` removes lines that do not match the pattern

Comment: `grep -v "toRemove.*toRemove" myFile > myOtherFile` should work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```sh
sed '/toRemove.*toRemove/d' myFile > myOtherFile
grep -v "toRemove.*toRemove" myFile > myOtherFile
```

`sed`: Note that `\t` matches a TAB char, and `!d` removes lines that do not match the pattern. So, you need to remove the `\` before `t` and remove `!` before the `d`.

`grep`: You should have used the `-v` option that reverses the result of the regex check (it will output all lines that do NOT match the pattern).

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/kDc0gZ):

```sh
s='This is a test toRemove first line
This is a test toRemove second line toRemove'
sed '/toRemove.*toRemove/d' <<< "$s"
# => This is a test toRemove first line
grep -v 'toRemove.*toRemove' <<< "$s"
# => This is a test toRemove first line
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/\<\(toRemove\)\>.*\<\1\>/d' file
```

This will delete a line that has 2 or more occurrences of the word `toRemove`.

To delete any line that contains the word `toRemove` beyond the first such line:

```
sed '/\<toRemove\>/{x;/./{x;d};x;h}' file
```